# Mod_rewrite not working in all environments

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So on a few servers the `.htaccess` works as expected. Locally Im having some issue.

The specific case is when `.htaccess` contains this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
## path relative to web root
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?action=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$  index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

There are a few other rows. But a comment states:

```
## rewrite everything else to index.php
```

So Im not including it to avoid confusion.

What happens is that this route:

```
http://localhost/index/myaction/?my_id=9
```

Will be handled by this `index.php` file:

```
public function index(){
    print_r($_REQUEST);
}
```

On the screen I see:

```
Array ( [my_id] => 9 )
```

So it appears that the "action"-parameter is not beeing sent. What's wrong?
In `httpd.conf` I added this:

```
<Directory "/appbasepath">
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

On other servers the "action"-parameter is beeing delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved. There was some conflict having directives both in htaccess and httpd.conf. Now I only have

```
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

and it works.